How to repass the nginx closed connection (499) to the associate service
I tries capture the close connection in the service associate with the ingress-nginx but I cant find a way. When this situation occur the log of nginx shows the correct status code on log:
172.21.0.224 - user [29/Apr/2024:13:21:41 +0000] "POST /execute HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/1.8.0_382)" 409 2.702 [service-8080] [] 172.21.72.106:8080 0 2.702 - da6c85d6276498086c97ccb1380ed096
But in the service the process continue. I think the correct behavior is the nginx close the connection with the service to interrupt the process.
Have a way to change this behavior?
In the documentation I only found the flag proxy_ignore_client_abort. But this flag doen't make sense for my problem.
